# Free online photo editor to resize photos and export to web format?

Tags: gratis, web-apps, image-processing, photography

I am traveling and don't have access to Photoshop because I am on a business laptop. I need to resize about 12 large photos and wondering if there is a free online photo editor where I can easily upload, resize, and then export photos to a web compressed format?

I would be open to installing a free lightweight program locally if that's a better option.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

GIMP and ImageMagick, among others, are gratis cross-platform image-editing programs that can resize images and convert between formats.

Comment: Using ImageMagick is rather difficult, as you have to use command-line to manipulate image. That is more suitable for experts. For beginners, stick with GIMP or PhotoScape.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with Pixlr, personally. https://pixlr.com/editor/. No batch editing and you have to endure Flash - but it'll get the job done in a pinch.